# How to run a script inside the <title></title> tag of a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a weird situation where I need to run a script inside of the `<title></title>` tags. I have no access to any of the others parts of the page, including the `<head></head>` tags. It has to be within the `<title></title>` tags (the reason is because we are dealing with an iframe response from a 3rd party server and we don't really have access to the full page.).

What I tried was:

```
<title>
  <script type="javascript">
    runMyFunction();
  </script>
</title>
```

The problem is that it interprets the whole thing as a script. Is there anything I could do to tell the browser to run that code as a script and not treat it as a string?

Comment: give more code. What do you put to your page, and what's in the iframe? How can you "inject" anything to the title... currently this question looks like you're asking us to do your homework...

Comment: I just want to know if it's even possible...

Comment: Also, forget the iframe part, that might have been a red herring. Let me generalize it. All I want to know really is if there is anyway to treat a string as a script rather than a string.

Comment: `I have a weird situation where I need to run a script inside of the tags` why would you and why *Inside* tags? Can you explain what you actually want and why exactly?

Comment: If you are in school and this is a school project, you should read whatever assignments you had already. The situation you describe is preposterous.

Comment: Agree, the situation is quite weird--sometimes we get handed down weird things at work! So anyway, it looks like it isn't possible based on @duskwuff's answer, that's really what I wanted to know so I don't invest more time down this path. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try the script injection in my answer first? Maybe it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<title>[trick</title>
  <script type="javascript">
    runMyFunction();
  </script>
<title>:)]</title>
```

Everyting between the [] is what you should set as title. Most probably it won't work though, 'cause if I were them I would properly encode whatever string you send, in order not to let you do any tricks...

Comment: That's an interesting concept; however, in the specification I linked above: "There must be no more than one `title` element per document." What happens if you have more than one isn't defined.

Comment: If you don't include the 2nd opening <title>, you won't have a 2nd title, just a slightly (anyway) not 100% correct html. In many browsers it still might work

Comment: Oh my goodness. Don't ever do this. Bad practice, and totally unnecessary.

Comment: of course it's a bad practice. It's a nasty hack. And I stated it that probably it wouldn't work. But we don't know how he "injects" his string anyway...

Comment: Cool. I hope it's a school project, otherwise think twice what you do, don't get into trouble ;)

Comment: @Gavriel it's not a school project. You'll be surprised, enough said :)

Comment: @James WRT your comment "totally unnecessary", I'm curious. What is the solution to the OP's problem?

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

[Per the HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element), the only permissible content of the `<title>` tag is plain text. Other tags, such as `<script>` tags, cannot be present in the context of a `<title>`.

Comment: FWIW, what @Prabhu is describing would be considered a Cross-Site Scripting attack. Even if it was possible, which it isn't, most modern browsers would block the code anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just rewrite `<title>` later?

```
<head>

<title>My Title</title>

<script>
  document.title = runMyFunction()
</script>

</head>
```